# MASM32 Reversing Digits

Tags: arrays, reverse, masm, cpu-registers, masm32

I am trying to make a very simple program that will list out values in a BYTE named array, then reverse the digits. This is the problem I was given:

Write a program to do the following: 
Use the BYTE directive to define the list of the 9 digits of your Student's ID number and name it array. Write instructions to reverse the order of those digits in array.

So far this is what I have:

```
.DATA
 array BYTE 9h, 6h, 4h, 5h, 2h, 8h, 7h, 4h, 2h

.CODE
  start:

   mov esi, 0
   mov edi, 0
   ; ?????

 call DumpRegs
 call WriteInt

exit
END start
```

I have used a BYTE for nine digits named array. I do not know how to start the reversal process. Is this done by LOOP? I understand the simple loop, however I am at a complete loss on this one. Any help or answer you can give is very much appreciated. Thank you in advance for helping me learn this material.

Comment: `LOOP` can only decrement `CX` and jump to a label if `CX` is above 0. It does not perform any other byte / word manipulation. You might need  `MOVSB` or `XCHG` altogether with `LOOP` to do your array processing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something i put together, hope it helps.

```
.DATA
array BYTE 9h, 6h, 4h, 5h, 2h, 8h, 7h, 4h, 2h
reversearray BYTE 9 DUP (0) ; assign storage for array that will contain reverse

.CODE
    mov ecx, SIZEOF array ; length of array is 9, so ecx contains 9
    lea esi, array ; address of the start of array
    lea edi, reversearray ; address of the start of reversearray

decarray:
    movzx eax, byte ptr [esi+ecx-1] ; byte from esi (array start) + ecx counter - 1
    mov byte ptr [edi], al ; store byte we have in al, into reverse array (edi)
    inc edi ; add 1 to reverse array location for next bytes storage when we loop again
    loop decarray ; if ecx is 0 we end, otherwise loop again and ecx will now be ecx-1

    ; do other stuff here, print our arrays etc
```